# RANSAC estimating Affine transformation

Tags: matlab, sift, ransac

For a image mosaic application, I took the matches of the descriptors and stored it in a matrix matches 2xM. I now want to apply Ransac with affine, so i got my random sample with was 2x3 matrix, then i tried applying the code

[tform,inlier1,inlier2] = estimateGeometricTransform(sample(1,:),sSample(2,:),'affine');

This doesn't seem to work because it requires that my columns to be 2, transposing it to 3x2 doesnt work as well since for affine i need 3 points of correspondences.

Matches also returns only the index of matched descriptors, how can I 
extract its coordinates and apply it to my tform transformation?

```
[f,d] = vl_sift(image1);
[f1,d2] = vl_sift(image2);
[matches, scores] = vl_ubcmatch(d, d2) ;

ranMatch = randperm(size(matches,2),3); 
sample = matches(:,ranMatch);
[tform,inlier1,inlier2] = 
estimateGeometricTransform(sample(1,:),sample(2,:),'affine');
```

Comment: You should input two matrices, each representing coordinates for points. It seems to me that you're inputting vectors instead of matrices. Please show all of your code, as described in [this page on to create a minimal, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: vl_ubcmatch gives the matching descriptor's index in a 2x562 matrix, and scores is the distance between them. I'm trying to use the matches' index to estimate an affline transformation. However, estimateGeometric  gives me the error that its not Mx2, if i do make it Mx2 it doesnt have 3 points anymore so affine doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your data to test this, nor your functions `vl_sift` and `vl_ubcmatch`. So please excuse any issues.

According to the [documentation](http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_sift.html), `f` and `f2` contain the coordinates of the points returned by `vl_sift`, and have a size of 4xM (possibly with different M), where the first two rows are the x and y coordinates.

I will also assume that `matches` is a 2xN array in which `matches(1,:)` are indicates into `f` and `matches(2,:)` are indices into `f2`, such that `f(1:2,matches(1,i))` is a point that corresponds to `f2(1:2,matches(2,i))`. **Please double-check this assumption, the documentation does not specify the output.**

You should be able to find the transformation between the two sets of points as follows:

```
matched_f = f(1:2,matches(1,:))';
matched_f2 = f2(1:2,matches(2,:))';
[tform,inlier1,inlier2] = estimateGeometricTransform(matched_f,matched_f2,'affine');
```

This will use all the matched points, and furthermore will discard outliers.

For more information, see the [documentation to `estimateGeometricTransform`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/estimategeometrictransform.html).

Comment: this throws the error Expected MATCHEDPOINTS1 to be of size Mx2, but it is of size 562x128.

Comment: That means that `d` and `d2` are not as I guessed. You will need to add more information to your question. What does `v1_sift` return? I don't even know where you got that function from...

Comment: @Hiya54Huy : I've adjusted the answer, but I'm still not sure even after reading the documentation. You'll have to test and debug from here. For example, when I said in the original version of the answer that I made an assumption about the size of `d`, it would have been easy for you to test this assumption, since you have `d` in your MATLAB workspace. Look at the variables and what they could mean, look at the function calls and what they expect, and try out things till you get it to work!

Comment: Doesn't seem to have any more errors! Thanks a lot for your patience and help.